# Find strings in R with this specific pattern "digitsXdigits"

Tags: r, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to clean a list of strings by finding strings with a particular pattern, but do not know how to write the regex to find them.

I am using grepl(), but do not know how to define the pattern.

The pattern is digits then [must include **x**, maybe special characters, letter] then digits again.

```
Here are some examples:           OUTPUT from grepl()
"kills kld ldks 2087x-2714"     TRUE
"sdlsn dklsk 4.75x25"           TRUE
"dkks klsdk  3x4x135"           TRUE
"djnlsdkl250shd"                FALSE
"kdls, skfndkl 24gx.75"         TRUE
"ski lsdkcm lskd 12.6"          FALSE
"klslc ksldml 3.0 dnjsl 67n030" FALSE
```

It's a little bit of a complicated pattern. Basically it must include digits on both sides of the x, but can also have special characters and numbers in the mix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack @Nate P. Can you include what your want your expected output to be and your code you are trying to run to help further define your question?

Comment: I'm just looking for TRUE or FALSE as included with each string. I can use grepl() to find this if I have a valid regex.

Comment: so ```"kdls, skfndkl x24g.75"```  would be ```FALSE```?

Comment: yes it would be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str_detect` from the stringr package.  I've added two additional test strings at the end of x.

The pattern is: a digit, zero or 1 occurrence of something that isn't a space, an x, zero or 1 occurrence of something that isn't a space, a digit

```
x <- c("kills kld ldks 2087x-2714",
       "sdlsn dklsk 4.75x25",
       "dkks klsdk  3x4x135",
       "djnlsdkl250shd",
       "kdls, skfndkl 24gx.75",
       "ski lsdkcm lskd 12.6",
       "klslc ksldml 3.0 dnjsl 67n030",
       "5x25",
       "kdls skfndkl x24g.75")

str_detect(x, "\\d\\S?x\\S?\\d")

#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there's no real restriction on what can occur on either side of the `x`, apart from at least some digits being present. So we can use `[^ ]` to match anything that's not a space:

```
grepl("[^ ]*\\d+[^ ]*x[^ ]*\\d+[^ ]*", x, perl = TRUE)
```

This gives your expected output on the example, but I can't guarantee that it'll work for all cases unless you can narrow down the restrictions.

As ikegami suggests, if all you need to do is *detect* these patterns (and not pull them out of the string), you can simplify this to:

```
grepl("\\d[^ ]*x[^ ]*\\d", x, perl = TRUE)
```

This could be a lot faster depending on your input, because things like `[^ ]*` can be very slow in regex (search "regex backtracking" to get an overview)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this pattern

```
grepl("\\d.*x.*\\d",x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**data**

```
x <- c("kills kld ldks 2087x-2714","sdlsn dklsk 4.75x25",
       "dkks klsdk  3x4x135","djnlsdkl250shd",
       "kdls, skfndkl 24gx.75","ski lsdkcm lskd 12.6",
       "klslc ksldml 3.0 dnjsl 67n030")
```

Comment: I suspect that Marius is correct that there can't be spaces between the digits and `x`. Maybe provide a solution for that too.

Comment: Do you mean `grepl("\\d[^ ]x[^ ]\\d",x)` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not familiar with R, but I suspect `\S` (escaped to `\\S`) can be used instead of `[^ ]`.

Comment: Thank you this solution is great!